# Problem with Scroll_Lock and Super

Tags: xubuntu

My keyboard lighting always on because Scroll Lock does not work.
After
xmodmap -e "add mod3 = Scroll_Lock"
Scroll Lock indicator LED turn on and the LED in keyboard turn off

If Scroll Lock off
Super + T,
Super + E
working fine
However if Scroll Lock on
Super + T.
Super + E
doesn't work.